# Using grunt registerTask targets

Tags: gruntjs

In my `Gruntfile.js` I've got:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    // ...
    uglify: {
        debug: {
            options: {
                mangle: false,
                compress: false,
                beautify: true
            }
        },
    },
});

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    //...
    'uglify',
    //...
]);
```

I'd like to have

```
grunt build
```

Create a ugilified version of my js code using the defaults to the uglify task, and

```
grunt build:debug
```

create an un-mangled version of the same code, but the :debug option doesn't seem to have an impact -- it runs the uglify task with the default options.  Any thoughts as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `build` task doesn't have a `debug` target. Your `uglify` task does. If you want your `build` task to run `uglify:debug` you would do:

`grunt.registerTask('build', ['uglify:debug']);`

Comment: I only want `build:debug` to run `uglify:debug`.   `build` should run `uglify` without debug.   Is it possible to pass this target value to the uglify task as specified (i.e. with/without :debug)?

Comment: Targets are tied to the task. So passing a target around isn't possible. You could fake it though by doing: `grunt.registerTask('build', ['uglify']);` and `grunt.registerTask('build:debug', ['uglify:debug']);`

Comment: Oh and also you could try this: http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#dynamic-alias-tasks which might be better for you're after.